# Android Generating debug apk it's working on my device but on other devices it gets installed but it never gets open

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am developing an app and it works fine on my device but when I try to generate a (Debug-Apk) and send it to my friends it gets installed but it never gets open.

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.realEstate">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RealState">
        <activity android:name="com.example.realEstate.RestorePasswordActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.realEstate.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.realEstate.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is my gradle file

```
  plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.realstate"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using a valid key to generate de APK ?

Comment: am not using a key am generating debug-apk file doing these steps 
from android studio menu-bar > building > building APKs
and waiting for the apk to get generated in app\build\outputs\apk\debug  Directory

Comment: Does the app stop at starting? If yes, try adding crash analytic to capture some logs, add some mechanics to capture system logs, it may help.

Comment: i dont know it does not event start .
it surly does not crash 
it just gives a black flash screen in just milliseconds

Comment: Please add the log for building apk command.